# How to replace grinder / cutoff wheel blades

Tags: angle-grinder, grinder

I have repeatedly faced hurdles removing/replacing blades on my (two) grinders. I do have the two-prong tool to turn counterclockwise. But usually that's not sufficient. The underside apparently needs to be vice-gripped - according to comments from another question [How to cut rebar with an angle grinder](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/229026/angle-grinder-blades-for-cutting-rebar)- I presume in the green rectangular area ?

[image]

I don't have any wrench that fits that description that is both:

- wide enough ~2 inches
- thin enough to fit below the blade and above the lower nut/bracket

How have folks done this: is there a special wrench for this - or other approach?

Comment: There usually is a lock button that locks the spindle on grinders.  Would be somewhere on the housing above the spindle.  Push it in and then the two prong tool can loosen the nut.

Comment: The lock button is also used to tighten the nut on the wheel, so the wheel stays tight on the spindle.

Comment: @crip659 ah see that now . pls make that an answer

Comment: @Ecnerwal I added those pics to the accepted answer below

Comment: Classic XY problem, you asked about how to implement  a solution to your problem (how to clamp backside of wheel with vice grip) instead of asking about your problem (how to stop disc from spinning free).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hand grinders have a button to lock the spindle to remove or tighten a grinder wheel.  It is usually on the housing above the wheel.  Usually just a push button, that pushes a steel rod into a hole in the spindle, to lock it from turning.  For safety should unplug grinder from power when changing grinder wheels.

**Original Poster here** I am adding a picture of the spindle lock to this accepted answer for full clarity.

*No Name Grinder*

[image: No Name Grinder]

*Bosch Grinder*

[image: Bosch Grinder]

Comment: In addition to this, it's not unusual that the nut has self-tightened during use. Be prepared to hit the 2-pin wrench with something heavy to loosen it. Also be prepared for hitting the 2-pin wrench to knock the wrench flying - apply more force progressively!

Comment: Also be prepared that on no-name grinders the act of hitting wrench will likely cause the locking pin to break the aluminum casting, thus ruining the grinder.